# Find Volume of solid using method of cylindrical shells

Tags: calculus

Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves y= 2(x^2) , y= x^3 about x -axis.

I have solved it and got the equation as

Limit = 0 to 8
. Shell radius= y
, shell height= sqrt(y/2)-cuberoot(y)

Is this correct??

Comment: Almost right. The shell height should be the negative of what you got. A picture will show that: on our interval, $y=x^3$ is below $y=2x^2$.

Comment: You are welcome. You did all the work. Just a minor sign error.